# Hausdorff linear topology

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove the following :

Given $(X, \tau)$ a topological vector space on $\mathbb{R}$, 
If {0} is closed then $\tau$ is separated.

Thank you.

Comment: This holds for any topological group, and relies on the fact that if $x \neq y$, then there exists two open sets separating $0$ and $x-y$.